# Sending data over UDP to a destination with multiple clients open

Tags: c#, udp

I am currently using this function to send data from the server to the clients

```
private static void send_message(string ip, string message)
{
    byte[] packetData = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    int port = 11000;

    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    client.SendTo(packetData, ep);
}
```

But this would mean a destination IP/port can only have one client open to receive the data, because having two clients open would mean one client can retrieve data that was meant for another (if I'm correct).. how do I solve this?

Receiving function:

```
private static Int32 port = 11000;
private static UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(port);

public static void receive_threaded()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            byte[] content = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPoint);

            if (content.Length > 0)
            {
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content);
                parseMessage(message);
            }
        }
    });
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: It seems like a pretty bad idea. Not only you can't know which one of your client will get the message but unless you use SocketFlags.Peek - the message will be erased from the queue and the other one won't get it. what are you trying to do? why not use TCP?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to implement some kind of dispatcher (my knowledge although is too limited to provide a full fledged answer to this). a uPNP-based TCP communication might suit your needs better maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should implement some kind of protocol so that your server has a "well known" port to accept connections. Use this port to inform your client ANOTHER port where the client must connect. Use a different port for each client.

Your client conects to the server at 11000. Your server assigns a unique port for the client, let's say 11001 for the firts client. Then the server opens a connection at 11001. The client closes connection at 11000 and opens a new connection at 11001 to receive the data.

2) Why UDP?

Comment: "Use a different port for each client" doesn't that make scalability impossible? Also, UDP because I have read up on networking for multiplayer games and UDP should be used to reduce latency, and because packages that failed to arrive in time are no longer relevant anyway since only the newest data matters in games. As an example, the position of a player from 5 seconds ago isn't relevant in the here and now. TCP would still put all newer packages on hold until that failed-to-deliver package was delivered.

Comment: No. You assign a port to a client, open the port and wait for connection, send data and close the port. This port is again available for another client.

Comment: Are you going to have more than one running instance of your game on a machine?

Comment: @Idov That is up to the person playing the game, it's not up to me. So I have to take the possibility into account

Comment: @Y.Ecarri Ok I see where you are coming from. I think I'll do a check if the IP of the client already has a connection 'open' on port 11001 on the server, and if it does, increment the port by 1 for each client. That would mean I could still get alot of people on port 11001, as long as they use different IP addresses, right?

Comment: @natli: If you use TCP, only one client can be connected to a port on your server in the same time. 
(also, there are only about 60,000 available ports so if you're expecting more clients than that simultaneously maybe TCP isn't the way :))

Comment: @Idov Um, I can accept multiple clients on one TCP port just fine. But I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say here because I am talking about UDP, not TCP.

Comment: @natly: Ok, you had a little confused here. Usually we don't talk about "connection"s in the context of UDP because it's a connectionless protocol. If you'll really implement some kind of protocol, give ID to each instance on the user machine so you can tell them apart and peek at the message (so you know the recipient is really the instance which should get the message) and then take it out of the message queue, you'll be just fine :)

Comment: I think I'm the one who's confused, because I don't think I need to have different ports on the *server* at all.. since only one server runs per IP guaranteed. I need different receiving ports for the *clients* because that's where the issue is at >.<

Comment: You should have only one server which handles all the clients (you might have several servers on several machines in order to reduce the load on each one, but that's another story). Many clients can talk with the server using UDP or TCP, so the server needs to send and receive data through many ports while each client uses only the port he "declared" to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to open a new socket at all. You already have each client's address and port, from the first packet they sent you. Just send a packet to that address:port. I absolutely don't get the other suggestion of setting up extra ports either.

Comment: Sorry but now I'm confused. The client sends something to the server over UDP, and based on this the server can send things back to the client? Who sais the port the server receives things from the client over, is also being used by the client to receive data in a loop? This is the first time using UDP, and I don't have a solid understanding of sockets to begin with, so could you please explain?

Comment: @nati Nobody said it. Every time you receive a datagram you also receive its source address and port number. Send the reply back there, using the same socket you received it on.